# Java Regex to count & delete spaces at beginning of a line?

Tags: java, regex

Searched other questions couldn't find any results.

I've written a regex to delete the spaces from the beginning of the line, but I need to count them and have them at the beginning of the line?

```java
scan.nextLine().replaceAll("\\s+", "").trim();
```

Above is the regex (it's in a while loop).  I'm reading in the text in a while loop to check if there is more text and it works fine but I don't know how I can print an integer with the number of spaces removed.

Comment: subString() and/or indexOf() and/or split()  will help you.. Any specific reason that is forcing you to use regex?

Comment: Will it give an integer of the amount ONLY at the beginning of the line?

Comment: yes... it will..split based on the first non-whitespace character. You r first array (of split() result) will have all the leading whitepsaces.. do arr.length on it...

Comment: No I don't need a regex I just need to have the spaces at the beginning removed and counted.

Answer (score 18):

If you want to count the white spaces at the beginning of a string:

```
String s = "  123456";
int count = s.indexOf(s.trim());
```

Comment: A little too simple: if the string has only whitespace it returns 0. So, if s.trim().isEmpty() return s.length().

Comment: What if there are spaces at the end? It will creat problem...

Comment: @Jabir No, it will not. The end of the argument passed to `String#indexOf` doesn't need to coincide with the end of the string. The argument might just as well be a single character.

Comment: It's probably not very fast for long strings. It must create a new, trimmed string and then find this complete string, comparing character by character, even though it just needs the index of the first non-whitespace character.

Answer (score 3):

Try this: This will give you count of leading and trailing spaces.

```
String str = "  Hello   ";
int strCount = str.length();
```

For getting leading spaces:

```
String ltrim = str.replaceAll("^\\s+","");
System.out.println(":"+ltrim+": spaces at the beginning:" + (strCount-ltrim.length()));
```

For getting trailing spaces:

```
String rtrim = str.replaceAll("\\s+$","");
System.out.println(":"+rtrim+": spaces at the end:" + (strCount-rtrim.length()));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use Pattern & Matcher, this way you can get the string that matches and the lenght of it.

```
String pattern = "\\s+";
String str = "     Hello   ";
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile(pattern).matcher(str);
if(matcher.find()){
    System.out.println(matcher.group().length());
    str = matcher.replaceAll("");
    System.out.println(str);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not just do like this?

```
String line = scan.nextLine();
String trimmedLine = line.replaceAll("^\\s+", "");
int spacesRemoved = line.length() - trimmedLine.length();
```

Answer (score 0):

Do like this

```
 public static void main(String args[]){

            String scan =" Hello World";

              String scan1= scan.replaceAll("^\\s*","");

                   int count = scan.length()-scan1.length();

            System.out.println("Number of Spaces removed at the begining"+count);

         }
```

Comment: This counts the number of occurrences of the pattern, and the pattern matches multiple spaces. It therefore cannot possibly count the number of spaces at the beginning of the line unless there is only one, as in your example. -1